# where do I find my network / web log file?

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Where do I find my proxy.log file? or where do I find any network log or web log on my system?

Answer (score 0):

In `/var/log` and its subdirectories.

Comment: Read `man rsyslogd;man rsyslog.conf;man logrotate` to see how log files are handled. Don't simply write to `/var/log/whatever`.